# GKE "no.scale.down.node.pod.not.enough.pdb" log even with existing PDB

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling

My GKE cluster is displaying "Scale down blocked by pod" note, and clicking it then going to the Logs Explorer it shows a filtered view with log entries for the pods that had the incident: `no.scale.down.node.pod.not.enough.pdb` . But that's really strange since the pods on the log entries having that message do have PDB defined for them. So it seems to me that GKE is wrongly reporting the cause of the blocking of the node scale down. These are the manifests for one of the pods with this issue:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ms-new-api-beta
  name: ms-new-api-beta
  namespace: beta
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: ms-new-api-beta
  type: NodePort
```

The Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ms-new-api-beta
  name: ms-new-api-beta
  namespace: beta
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ms-new-api-beta
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict: 'true'
      labels:
        app: ms-new-api-beta
    spec:
      containers:
        - command:
            - /deploy/venv/bin/gunicorn
            - '--bind'
            - '0.0.0.0:8000'
            - 'newapi.app:app'
            - '--chdir'
            - /deploy/app
            - '--timeout'
            - '7200'
            - '--workers'
            - '1'
            - '--worker-class'
            - uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
            - '--log-level'
            - DEBUG
          env:
            - name: ENV
              value: BETA
            
          image: >-
            gcr.io/.../api:${trigger['tag']}
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 5
            httpGet:
              path: /rest
              port: 8000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            periodSeconds: 20
            timeoutSeconds: 30
          name: ms-new-api-beta
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
              name: http
              protocol: TCP
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /rest
              port: 8000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 2
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 150m
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
          startupProbe:
            failureThreshold: 30
            httpGet:
              path: /rest
              port: 8000
            periodSeconds: 120
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: gcp-docker-registry
```

The Horizontal Pod Autoscaler:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: ms-new-api-beta
  namespace: beta
spec:
  maxReplicas: 5
  minReplicas: 2
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: ms-new-api-beta
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 100
```

And finally, the Pod Disruption Budget:

```
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: ms-new-api-beta
  namespace: beta
spec:
  minAvailable: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ms-new-api-beta
```

Answer (score 1):

`no.scale.down.node.pod.not.enough.pdb` is not complaining about the lack of a PDB. It is complaining that, if the pod is scaled down, it will be [*in violation* of the existing PDB(s)](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler-visibility#noscaledown-node-level-reasons).

The "budget" is how much disruption the Pod can permit. The platform will not take any intentional action which violates that budget.

There may be another PDB in place that would be violated. To check, make sure to review pdbs in the pod's namespace:

```
kubectl get pdb
```

Comment: There are not dupplicated pdb. As you've seen, my pdb is set to `minAvailable: 0` so the budget for disruption is 100%. It should not log that entry saying "not enough pdb"

Comment: That is odd. I'd suggest deleting the PDB temporarily and seeing if you can scale down. If you can, it does sound like a GKE bug.

Comment: I see the same behaviour. I have confirmed the PDB is correct and there is no other conflicting PDB. Running GKE 1.22.15-gke.2500